# Memory leak in stringWithCString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I encounter memory leak with `stringWithCString`, can anybody find the memory leak in `stringWithCstring` function?

```
SomeView *detailViewController = [[SomeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.test = [NSString stringWithCString:"abc" encoding:UTF8_ENCODING];
```

the property in SomeView for test variable is

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* test;
```

Is my property declared correctly?

Comment: What is `UTF8_ENCODING` and why are you using that instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: yes, NSUTF8StringEncoding should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you releasing the string in your `[SomeView dealloc]` method like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.test = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, It's work. May I know why, supposedly  stringWithCString should autorelease the memory?

Comment: @tsong it's the copy of the string that wasn't being released; as you own the copy, you are responsible for releasing it by passing `nil` to the setter method as shown.

Comment: Not all NSStrings are immutable. NSMutableStrings are NSStrings, but are mutable. It's better to use `copy` in case you pass in a mutable string from somewhere. (Bonus: There is no performance advantage to `strong`/`retain` because an immutable NSString will respond to `copy` by simply retaining and returning itself.)

Comment: Also, immutable NSStrings just call retain in their copy methods, so it's not really any more expensive to use copy. Perhaps you'd edit your answer to remove the comment about using retain?

Comment: @JesseRusak That's interesting, and I wasn't aware of that.  Can I ask how you know this, and is that the case for all immutable Cocoa classes?  If not then perhaps it's better to ignore this implementation detail and advise the use of `retain` over `copy`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, I don't know it for sure, but Apple's docs on NSCopying suggest implementing copy "by retaining the original instead of creating a new copy when the class and its contents are immutable". I would guess it's the same for all immutable Cocoa classes. But I think you misunderstood my comment: you want to *almost always* use `copy` for NSString properties, and the implementation detail is that it'll use retain when it's safe to and actually copy the data if the original object was mutable.

Comment: @JesseRusak OK, I have removed the comment.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use to "detect" the leak, how reliable is that?

Now I've never used properties, but the code above looks pretty correct -- the string should get released. The "stringWithCString:" will autorelease the string anyway, so there's no problem. However, the "copy" in your property seems to indicate that it makes a copy (huh? Surprise!) of the string, and even if I assume that object-type properties are released when the owning object dies -- if the owning object never dies then the copied string will never be released.

Maybe the memory leak detector really meant to say that the copy of that string is never released because you forgot to release the "detailViewController"? That copy would still be in the same source code line, so even if the memory leak detector can give an accurate location but only provides a line number you could be misled...

Comment: If the questioner is not using ARC, then they need to release the copy themselves when its owner dies. See trojanfoe's answer.